# Correct type hint error thrown by PHPStan on UserInterface in Symfony project

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.4, type-hinting, phpstan

I've recently started using **PHPStan** (version 0.12.19) on a **Symfony 3.4** project but I'm getting an error which seems like it should have been simple to resolve but I'm struggling to figure out.

Currently running at level 7. Here's the error I get when I run:

`vendor/bin/phpstan analyse`

```
------ --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Line   src/AppBundle/Controller/MapController.php
 ------ --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  94     Parameter #1 $user of static method AppBundle\Entity\MapMarker::createMapMarker() expects
         Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface, object given.
```

This is the important parts of **MapController.php**:

```
    $user = $this->getUser();

     $mapMarker = MapMarker::createMapMarker(
            $user,
            $latitude,
            $longitude
        );
```

The getUser method is the Symfony one so I can't change this part: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/3.4/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/ControllerTrait.php#L444:

```
/**
     * Get a user from the Security Token Storage.
     *
     * @return UserInterface|object|null
     *
     * @throws \LogicException If SecurityBundle is not available
     *
     * @see TokenInterface::getUser()
     *
     * @final since version 3.4
     */
    protected function getUser()
    {
        if (!$this->container->has('security.token_storage')) {
            throw new \LogicException('The SecurityBundle is not registered in your application. Try running "composer require symfony/security-bundle".');
        }

        if (null === $token = $this->container->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()) {
            return null;
        }

        if (!\is_object($user = $token->getUser())) {
            // e.g. anonymous authentication
            return null;
        }

        return $user;
    }
```

And the important parts of **MapMarker.php**:

```
/**
     * @param UserInterface $user
     * @param double $latitude
     * @param double $longitude
     */
    private function __construct(UserInterface $user, $latitude, $longitude) {
        $this->createdBy = $user;
        $this->latitude = $latitude;
        $this->longitude = $longitude;
    }

    /**
     * @param UserInterface $user
     * @param double $latitude
     * @param double $longitude
     * @return MapMarker
     */
    public static function createMapMarker(UserInterface $user, $latitude, $longitude): MapMarker
    {
        return new self($user, $latitude, $longitude);
    }
```

When I dump out `$user instanceof UserInterface` it returns true - so as far as I can tell it IS passing a UserInterface object, not just an "object" as PHPStan is indicating.

And finally, here's my phpstan.neon config file:

```
parameters:
    level: 7
    paths:
        - src
        - tests
    checkGenericClassInNonGenericObjectType: false
    checkMissingIterableValueType: false
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you at least got whats the proble: The return type of the method `getUser` is `@return UserInterface|object|null` while `createMapMarker` expects an instance of `UserInterface`.

Before calling `createMapMarker` you should check that the return value of `getUser` is actually an instance of `UserInterface` and probably a simple `/** @var UserInterface $user */` right on top the the `$user` variable declaration will fix.

Comment: Wow.. why I didn't think of that I'll never know! Brain freeze :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A more convenient way to handle it (imo) is to add

```
/**
 * @method User|null getUser()
 */
```

in top of your controller class (with the proper import)

```
use App\Entity\User

/**
 * @method User|null getUser()
 */
class MapController extends...
```